# pygame.key.get_pressed() does not work, why?

Tags: python, debugging, pygame, game-development

Can someone please help Im only new to this and cant figure out why there is just no response at all from the game when i press a or d
Im using some code form a youtube video by tech with tim, ive already finished the video and have a working game and now im trying to make my own thing but im really stuck on this now.

```
import pygame
import os

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1440, 900
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("The Game")

background = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', 'blackish.jpg')), (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
bar = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "bar.png")), (250, 100))
SHIP = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "spaceship_red.png")), (100, 100)), 180)


WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

ShipWidth = (200)
ShipHeight = (200)

direction = "left"

def barsleft(BarMove):
    BarMove.x -= 1

def barsright(BarMove):
    BarMove.x += 1


def draw(player, BarMove):
    WIN.blit(background, (0, 0))
    WIN.blit(bar, (BarMove.x, BarMove.y))
    WIN.blit(SHIP, (player.x, player.y))

    pygame.display.update()


def PlayerMove(player, keys_pressed):
     if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] and player.x > 0: #left
        player.x -= 2
     if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d] and player.x + ShipWidth/2 < WIDTH: #right
        player.x += 2



def game(ShipWidth, ShipHeight):
    player = pygame.Rect(620, 700, ShipWidth, ShipHeight)
    BarMove = pygame.Rect(600, 550, 250, 100)

    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    edge = False

    run = True
    while run == True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()


        
        if BarMove.x > 0 and edge == False:
            barsleft(BarMove)
            if BarMove.x < 50:
                edge = True
        if edge == True:
            barsright(BarMove)
            if BarMove.x > WIDTH - 300:
                edge = False


        
        PlayerMove(player, keys_pressed)
        draw(player, BarMove)


game(ShipWidth, ShipHeight)
```

i want to be able to hold down the keys so im not using get event, ive tried messing around with different function ands stuff but nothing is working

Answer (score 2):

> i want to be able to hold down the keys ... but nothing is working

Well, sure, you called `get_pressed()` that **one** time.
Which was nice.
But then you never call it again within the game loop, and you need to.

```
def game
    ...
    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    ...
    while run == True:
        ...
        PlayerMove(player, keys_pressed)  # which inspects 2nd param for K_{a,d}
```

Simply move that assignment down within the loop:

```
    while run == True:
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        ...
```

Now if the state of the keyboard changes a few seconds into game play,
that variable will *also* change, and PlayerMove can respond appropriately.

---

I recommend you format your source code with
"$ [black](https://pypi.org/project/black) *.py"

```
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1440, 900
...
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
...
ShipWidth = (200)
ShipHeight = (200)
```

Assigning WIDTH and HEIGHT is very nice.
Similarly for WHITE, and the `(` `)` paren notation
happens to match how python will display a tuple.

OTOH, the parens around `ShipWidth` and height are
distracting and perhaps misleading.
Please understand that they are superfluous and do nothing for you.
In particular, they're not magically going to produce a tuple,
given that there's no comma there.
Recommend you delete them.
Simplest way to do that is to let `black` tidy up your source code for you.